# Mongo DB installation issue

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I installed mongo DB by using `docs of mongo DB`. But when I tried this command in ubuntu terminal, I got this error:
`Command used:`

```
sudo mongod
```

Error:

```
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: create folder using this sudo mkdir -p /data/db and run mongo as below 
sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command to create a directory -

```
sudo mkdir /data/db
```

and then run

```
sudo mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed mongo as a service (for example, using the following docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), simply execute:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Otherwise, if you simply wish to try mongo without any specific configuration, you can supply a directory for the db files by executing:

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/db &
```

Comment: When I try to start mongod, it says `"Service already started"`. I'll create folders

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Mongo Setup on AWS Unbuntu 14.0** - *By Hrushikesh Kulkarni*

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org sudo apt-get install php5 sudo apt-get install apache2 sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev sudo pecl install mongo

Add Below Stuff in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/20121212" extension=mongo.so sudo service apache2 restart

Create php File in /var/www/html Run file in browser and find Extension "Mongo"

Answer (score 0):

If you have created Test123 folder then

Run following command to restart the mongodb service

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Then change the db for the mongodb 
Use following command

```
sudo mongod --dbpath Test123
```

Here Test123 is directory that you have created on specific location.